# Show matplotlib plot in rqt

Tags: rqt, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a plot in matplotlib, which I am using to control the robot. I have `plt.connect('motion_notify_event', self.moveRobot)` function, which controls the robot. Below is the code snippet:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim((xmin, xmax))
ax.set_ylim((ymin, ymax))

fig.canvas.draw()
fig.tight_layout()
fig.canvas.draw()

plt.connect('button_press_event',self.mouseClick)
plt.connect('motion_notify_event', self.moveRobot)
plt.show()
```

I want to see this plot inside rqt. Any suggestions, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275557/show-matplotlib-plot-in-rqt/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2017-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am able to do it by following [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) tutorial. Thank you very much.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2017-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0